# iOS How to download data from database in array parse Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

i have one issues, i have database in one class, and i this class i have 1 row with 12 values, which are will not changing.
So i want to **load all data in array.**

Now i load data for separate variable.
My code:

```
var JAN = Double()
var FEB = Double()
var MAR = Double()
var APR = Double()
var MAY = Double()
var JUN = Double()
var JUL = Double()
var AUG = Double()
var SEP = Double()
var OCT = Double()
var NOV = Double()
var DEC = Double()
```

And code to load data:

```
     let query = PFQuery(className: "result")
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        for object in objects! {
            self.JAN = object["JAN"] as! Double
            self.FEB = object["FEB"] as! Double
            self.MAR = object["MAR"] as! Double
            self.APR = object["APR"] as! Double
            self.MAY = object["MAY"] as! Double
            self.JUN = object["JUN"] as! Double
            self.JUL = object["JUL"] as! Double
            self.AUG = object["AUG"] as! Double
            self.SEP = object["SEP"] as! Double
            self.OCT = object["OCT"] as! Double
            self.NOV = object["NOV"] as! Double
            self.DEC = object["DEC"] as! Double
        }

    }
```

All thi data which i load in separate variables, i want to save in one array.
So i wand to load this all data in one array, how can i do this?

Comment: create `[Double]()` array and append your value in array.

Comment: All thi data which i load in separate variables, i want to save in one array.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Swift because this shouldn’t be a question on SO, you can create a simple struct for this or use tuples as in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Can use array of touples**
Assuming you have single `object` from `objects`

```
var array = [(name: String, value: Double)]()
let query = PFQuery(className: "result")
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
    if let object in objects?.first {
        array.append((name: "JAN", value: object["JAN"] as! Double))
        array.append((name: "FEB", value: object["JAN"] as! Double))
        ...
    }
}
// use it as
for each in array {
    print("\(each.name): \(each.value)")
}
```

***You can also add all (key, value) pairs without specifying keys from `object` depending on you `object` type. If it is Dictionary then***

```
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
    if let object in objects?.first {
        for key in object.keys {
            array.append((name: key, value: object[key] as! Double))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "result")
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
             ServerData.init(JAN: object["JAN"], FEB: object["FEB"], MAR: object["MAR"], APR: object["APR"], MAY: object["MAY"], JUN: object["JUN"], JUL: object["JUL"], AUG: object["AUG"], SEP: object["SEP"], OCT: object["OCT"], NOV: object["NOV"], DEC: object["DEC"])

        }
```

Take `serverData struct class`

```
import Foundation
struct ServerData {

var JAN :Double?
var FEB : Double?
var MAR : Double?
var APR : Double?
var MAY : Double?
var JUN : Double?
var JUL : Double?
var AUG : Double?
var SEP : Double?
var OCT : Double?
var NOV : Double?
var DEC : Double?

    init(JAN: Double,FEB: Double,MAR:Double,APR:Double,MAY:Double,JUN:Double,JUL:Double,AUG:Double,SEP:Double,OCT:Double,NOV:Double,DEC: Double) {
        self.JAN = JAN
        self.FEB = FEB
        self.MAR = MAR
        self.APR = APR
        self.MAR = MAY
        self.JUN = JUN
        self.JUL = JUL
        self.AUG = AUG
        self.SEP = SEP
        self.OCT = OCT
        self.NOV = NOV
        self.DEC = DEC
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP want.